# how to sum only numbers and show strings separately in var char column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, sum

Below is the sample data

```
create table temp (userid int , rid varchar(10), value varchar(100))
insert into temp(userid,rid,value)
values(1,'D01','3'),
(1,'D01','4'),
(2,'C01','hey'), 
(2,'C01','1')
```

expected output:

```
1,'D01','7'
2,'C01','hey'
2,'C01','1'
```

I tried below code and it is throwing error

```
select distinct 
    userid,rid,
    case when ISNUMERIC(value) = 1 
        THEN SUM(cast(value as int)) over (partition by userId,rid order by userid)
        else value
    end as [Value]
from temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Going to repeat my comment here first:

> Why are you storing numerical data in a `varchar` in the first place? Also, `ISNUMERIC` is a terrible function, it gives both false positives and negatives. You're using SQL Server 2012 so use `TRY_CONVERT`, however, you're far better off fixing your design.

If you don't believe about `ISNUMERIC` being bad, many have written about it including [myself](https://wp.larnu.uk/stop-using-isnumeric-its-probably-wrong/), [Phil Factor](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/), [Erik Darling](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric/), and more.

You *can* achieve what you're after with some truly *odd* logic but I ***strongly*** suggest fixing your design:

```
SELECT userid,
       rid,
       ISNULL(CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,[value]) IS NULL THEN [value] END,SUM(TRY_CONVERT(int,[value]))) AS [value]
       --ISNULL returns the data type of the first parameter, so will implicit compvert the SUM to a varchar
FROM dbo.temp
GROUP BY userid,
         rid,
         CASE WHEN TRY_CONVERT(int,[value]) IS NULL THEN [value] END;
```